# serving GAE applications over http

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl

I have implemented an application on GAE which can be accessible through `https://<my_app_id>.appspot.com`. Now I have a custom domain registered with `Register.com`. As described in GAE documentation I have mapped my custom domain to `https://<my_app_id>.appspot.com` and I see my application getting served from my custom domain. But I see requests are failed with error `"SSL required to perform this operation"`. But I don't have any SSL certificate. And Can I serve my application without `SSL`? I mean just using `http`

**UPDATED:**
Response on executing url `curl -v example.org/_ah/api/myapi/v1/package/ -o /dev/null`

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1fa7e80
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1fa7e80) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to mydomain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ipaddress...
* Connected to mydomain.com (ipaddress) port 80 (#0)
> GET /_ah/api/myapp/v1/package/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: mydomain.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 12:26:50 GMT
< Vary: X-Origin
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
* Server GSE is not blacklisted
< Server: GSE
< Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{ [data not shown]
Warning: Failed to create the file /dev/null: No such file or directory
* Failed writing body (0 != 9)
* Failed writing data
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 9)
```

Comment: Welcome to the post-Snowden Internet, where everyone wants to make SSL mandatory, but nobody's bothered to make it convenient.

Comment: ssl is not required, you can use plain http

Comment: @IgorArtamonov but I see failured request asking for SSL encryption

Comment: so you have a link somewhere with `https://`? replace it with `http://`

Comment: @IgorArtamonov No I don't have any such url in my app. App urls are relative paths to http://<myapp>.appspot.com

Comment: where from such requests are coming? just a browser user following your link? standard browser, or a browser configured to require ssl?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I am using chrome on my laptop and I am directly typing the custom domain name without https

Comment: please provide output of `curl -v http://youcustomdomain/ -o /dev/null`

Comment: Updated question with response

Comment: @IgorArtamonov one thing I found that cloud endpoints does not work on custom domain?

Comment: oh, i see, you're trying to use endpoint? as per doc: "Google Cloud Endpoints requires SSL". I thought you're talking about your own servlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two things you've missed from docs:

> Google Cloud Endpoints requires SSL. If you need to access your backend API in a system not supporting SSL, you'll need to either update the system to support SSL or use a proxy.

and

> Google Cloud Endpoints does not support custom domains.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

Comment: oh! if I add SSL to custom domain then can I access cloud endpoints?

Comment: no, seems that Google Cloud Endpoints does not support custom domains at all

Comment: If I use Compute Engine VMs(Google's) then can I use datastore service from App Engine?

Comment: btw, i don't think cloud endpoints as a service are exists for Compute Engine